# Is it possible to use the browser developer tools to inspect ViewData in an asp.net mvc project?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on an asp.net mvc project where I have some values stored in `ViewData["customers"]`. I was wondering if it's possible to inspect these values using the developer tools in Chrome, the same way I can do with cookies, session storage, local storage etc. I understand that I could just print them out in view, but I find that a bit cumbersome to do every time I'd like to inspect these values quickly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASP.Net MVC concerns itself with everything *before* the page is sent to the browser. Your browser, logically, is only concerned with the page that was *actually* sent.

Unless the application gave some hints (meta tags, user recognizable structure, ...), your browser **isn't even aware what type of application sent the page**. Let alone that it could access something that is in memory of that unknown application.

So in short, no, that's not possible.

`I understand that I could just print them out in view, but I find that a bit cumbersome to do every time I'd like to inspect these values quickly.`

Printing it into the page (e.g. as a HTML comment) is an option, and the only one I can think of.

**Edit** Removed my example and afterthought. It was silly, because most important data are classes or lists, for which a `.ToString()` is completely useless.